# Bat script's remote path not working with "SET Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users"

Tags: batch-file, remote, user-folders

```
@ECHO OFF
:ProfilDeleter
SET /P PC=Enter Remote Ip/HostName (for Exit press M): 
if [%PC%]==[] cls && @echo you should fill && goto ProfilDeleter
if %PC%==m goto :Menu
if %PC%==M goto :Menu

SET /p NotToBeDeleted=Your UserName: 
cls
::HERE NOT WORKING
SET Profiles=\\%PC%\C$\Users

PushD "%Profiles%"
if /I Not "%CD%"=="%Profiles%" (ECHO. Unable to find %Profiles% exiting)&Pause&goto Menu
FOR /F "Delims=" %%I in ('Dir /AD /B ^|FindStr /I /V /C:"%NotToBeDeleted%" /C:"ADMINI~1" /C:"Public" /C:"Default" /C:"Administrator"') DO RD /Q /S "%%I"
PopD
pause
:Menu
Exit
```

I made batch in order to delete Remote User Profile Folders But I can't run for Remote PCs? Where is the problem in the script?

Comment: Please read [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: Why do you post the same question to more StackExchange sites? . Accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35476491/3439404